# Divs in input using ant design

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, antd

I need to create an effect like the one in tags on this site.
[image]

So I need an input with styled spans/divs inside. The simplest way would be to use .map on an array in state, and separate the elements with a space or `;`

But I am also using Ant Design. I was curious if said library has a way of doing it that's built in?

Target design:

[image]

Comment: And what is actually your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Ant Design has a multi-select component.
Take a look at https://ant.design/components/select/